# GPT partition scheme

Tags: system-installation, partitioning, gpt

I'm reinstalling my operating systems to use GPT and am willing to do it properly this time... I'm intending to use the following partition scheme:

```
sda
|-- sda1  500 MiB EFI
|-- sda2  100 GiB Linux
|-- sda3  100 GiB Linux
|-- sda4  128 MiB Windows System Partition
|-- sda5  422 GiB Windows
|-- sda6  300 GiB Files repo
|-- sda7    8 GiB Swap
```

Any comments here? I've read that GPT provides fault-tolerance by keeping copies of the partition table in the first and last sectors of the disk; shouldn't I leave some free space at the end of the disk then? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your system UEFI. Then you have to have gpt for Windows to boot, or Windows only boots from gpt drives with UEFI. Windows in UEFI has specific requirements. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744301%28WS.10%29.aspx Ubuntu will just need efi partition where you will install both Windows & grub's efi boot loaders. If you create gpt using LInux tools like gdisk or gparted space will be allocated at end of drive for backup gpt partition table. Windows tools sometimes put backup in middle of drive which is incorrect and causes issues.

Comment: If you're installing Linux after Windows, chronologically,  intuitively Windows and Windows System Partition would be before Linux...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks great, but my only concern would be your Micrcosoft Reserved Partition (MSR) partition which should be immediately after your UEFI System Partition (ESP).

---

If you want to be a perfectionist the MSR should also be 128 Mb (megabytes), not 128 MiB (mebibytes). I wouldn't bother getting that specific though. I believe Microsoft incorrectly refers to megabytes so your sizing should actually be correct anyways. However if you have a Windows installation or Windows installation disc you could verify your MSR shows up as the correct size in megabytes under Windows. You can do this in the Windows terminal by typing "diskpart" which is a cli partitioning tool. Then "select disk0", and "list partitions".

Keep in mind that unless you are using software that is designed to use hidden sectors you don't actually need an MSR. I personally don't bother with it, but if you're not sure then it's best to have one.

You may also want to create a 100 Mb System partition which would come before the MSR.

There is a section on MSR partitions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn640535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Information about Microsofts recommened partition setup (System Partition, ESP, MSR, and etc):
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799232%28v=ws.10%29.aspx#SystemPartitions

Comment: Why should the MSR immediately follow the ESP?

Comment: @psusi: If you do not, Windows Installer will automatically allocate another MSR just before Windows FS partition.

Answer (score 0):

It is vital for all systems running Windows 8 in UEFI mode to have fast boot and hibernated shutdown turned off, as well as fast boot in the UEFI.  This keeps you from losing data on your Windows install.

This is the most proper way I have found to do a Dual Boot with UEFI and GPT.

First off, you cannot run dual boot configuration with Windows 7/8 in UEFI and any *nix in CSM.  Grub will not be able to see the Windows 7/8 installation (in my experience).  Either way:

If you want Ubuntu on the same disk as Windows 7/8, here are the steps to go through:

1) Install Windows first.  Then, [Turn off Windows Fast Boot](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html)

2) [Windows expects a certain partition scheme](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824839.aspx) to be used.  Let me show you a diagram:

[(Windows RE Tools[Optional])(EFI System Partition)(Microsoft Reserved Partition[may be omitted after installation following a nasty procedure])(Windows 7/8)(Anything else)]

You can use your favorite tool to edit the Windows 7/8 install partition.  I prefer Gparted, but any good disk partitioning tool can handle this.  ***Backup your Windows install*** first.  Then, resize the Windows 8.1 partition so that you have enough space for another OS.  I prefer to give my Linux installs about 50-100 GB of space (for expandability).

3)  Download your Ubuntu (use 64 bit only and I suggest 13.10) iso and put it on some media (CD/DVD/USB/(insert your preferred media here)) by using your favorite tool (most people prefer Rufus) or dd.

4) Shut off Secure Boot and Fast Boot in the UEFI.  ***DO NOT TURN ON LEGACY BOOTING (if your motherboard supports UEFI only booting without Secure Boot and Fast Boot on.)***

5) Insert your install media and install Ubuntu in the partition you made earlier.  Make sure that for your EFI boot partition, you make the installer use the EFI System Partition already created by Windows 8.1.  The partition should be something like sdXn (replace X with the drive it is on and n with the partition number, such as /dev/sda2), but this could be different.  ***DO NOT REFORMAT THIS PARTITION!!***  You are only going to tell the installer to use it as the EFI partition.  It will put the grubx64.efi bootloader for Ubuntu in this location.

6) With that done, continue the install as normal and set up your partitions as you see fit.  Once the install is finished, you should be able to boot into Jessie easily.

If you are trying to fix an existing install of Ubuntu, you will need to do:

`sudo apt-get install grub-efi-amd64`

`sudo modprobe efivars`

`sudo grub-install /dev/sdx` (x being the drive Ubuntu is installed on)

`sudo update-grub`

From there, the UEFI ***should*** use Grub-EFI as the bootloader. I have not found a way to get the Windows 8 bootloader to see and allow Linux to boot in UEFI.  YYMV.

Answer (score 0):

> shouldn't I leave some free space at the end of the disk then? Am I missing something here?

No; the space used by the partition table itself is invisible and the partitioner will not let you try to use it.